# Why is Azure AD B2C saying my password is incorrect?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have built a custom user flow in Azure AD B2C. It is almost a direct copy of this sample policy for doing JIT migration of users: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/jit-migration-v2.

I have disabled Facebook, Google, sign-up & password reset. This leaves me with a simple sign-in form. Signing in with a user the first time will successfully migrate the user to Azure AD B2C. Signing in with the same user a second time is however showing me the error `The username or password provided in the request are invalid.` I tried numerous times - including getting Chrome to autofill the credentials, and I am certain that the credentials are correct (and the same credentials were used with the initial sign-in).

I tried adding a standard `SignUpSignIn` user flow, and with this flow, I am able to sign in correctly with the same user credentials that were just migrated to the directory. So, the password must have been saved correctly.

I must have messed something up in my custom flow, which breaks the `login-NonInteractive` validation technical profile (I guess). I tried comparing my files with the sample files, but I can't spot the problem :(

Any help is much appreciated.

SignUpOrSignIn.xml: https://pastebin.com/M1iYaAFU

TrustFrameworkExtension.xml: https://pastebin.com/psA0mNKH

TrustFrameworkBase.xml: https://pastebin.com/xZy8VfDE

(unfortunately, I could not include all the files in the question text, as it would exceed the max question length, so I had to put them on Pastebin)

### UPDATE

Here is the log from Application Insights:

```
[
  {
    "Kind": "Headers",
    "Content": {
      "UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint": "urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights",
      "CorrelationId": "403025e3-e919-4662-a000-e98e874947fa",
      "EventInstance": "Event:SELFASSERTED",
      "TenantId": "likvidostaging.onmicrosoft.com",
      "PolicyId": "B2C_1A_JITMigraion_signup_signin"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Transition",
    "Content": {
      "EventName": "SELFASSERTED",
      "StateName": "Initial"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.CrossSiteRequestForgeryValidationHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "Statebag": {
        "MACHSTATE": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.7243667Z",
          "k": "MACHSTATE",
          "v": "Initial",
          "p": true
        },
        "JC": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.5681012Z",
          "k": "JC",
          "v": "en-US",
          "p": true
        },
        "Complex-CLMS": {
          "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword"
        },
        "ORCH_CS": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:33.6955832Z",
          "k": "ORCH_CS",
          "v": "1",
          "p": true
        },
        "ORCH_IDX": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.6931571Z",
          "k": "ORCH_IDX",
          "v": "0",
          "p": true
        },
        "RA": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.6931571Z",
          "k": "RA",
          "v": "0",
          "p": true
        },
        "RPP": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.5681012Z",
          "k": "RPP",
          "v": "OAUTH2",
          "p": true
        },
        "RPIPP": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.5681012Z",
          "k": "RPIPP",
          "v": "OAuth2ProtocolProvider",
          "p": true
        },
        "OTID": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.5681012Z",
          "k": "OTID",
          "v": "likvidostaging.onmicrosoft.com",
          "p": true
        },
        "APPMV": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.5681012Z",
          "k": "APPMV",
          "v": "V2",
          "p": true
        },
        "IC": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.6931571Z",
          "k": "IC",
          "v": "True",
          "p": true
        },
        "MSG(81f99852-33b6-41f3-87fd-506d1b2e6d41)": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.6931571Z",
          "k": "MSG(81f99852-33b6-41f3-87fd-506d1b2e6d41)",
          "v": "{\"TenantId\":\"likvidostaging.onmicrosoft.com\",\"PolicyId\":\"B2C_1A_JITMigraion_signup_signin\",\"RedirectUri\":\"https://jwt.ms/\",\"AdditionalParameters\":{\"p\":\"B2C_1A_JITMIGRAION_SIGNUP_SIGNIN\"},\"Nonce\":\"defaultNonce\",\"ClientId\":\"bc1ad362-fd3c-4f02-9922-231ed9b1fdb8\",\"ResponseType\":\"code\",\"ResponseRedirector\":{\"URI\":\"https://jwt.ms\",\"D\":false,\"WF\":true,\"R\":false},\"Scope\":\"openid\",\"AppModelVersion\":1,\"ScopedProviders\":[]}",
          "p": true,
          "t": "OAuth2"
        },
        "IMESSAGE": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.6931571Z",
          "k": "IMESSAGE",
          "v": "81f99852-33b6-41f3-87fd-506d1b2e6d41",
          "p": true
        },
        "EID": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:31.7087357Z",
          "k": "EID",
          "v": "urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0",
          "p": true
        },
        "CMESSAGE": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:33.6955832Z",
          "k": "CMESSAGE",
          "v": "81f99852-33b6-41f3-87fd-506d1b2e6d41",
          "p": true
        },
        "ComplexItems": "_MachineEventQ, REPRM, TCTX"
      },
      "PredicateResult": "True"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsDisplayControlActionRequestHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": false,
      "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsClaimVerificationRequestHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.SelfAssertedMessageValidationHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": false,
      "RecorderRecord": {
        "Values": [
          {
            "Key": "Validation",
            "Value": {
              "Values": [
                {
                  "Key": "SubmittedBy",
                  "Value": null
                },
                {
                  "Key": "ProtocolProviderType",
                  "Value": "SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"
                },
                {
                  "Key": "TechnicalProfileEnabled",
                  "Value": {
                    "EnabledRule": "Always",
                    "EnabledResult": true,
                    "TechnicalProfile": "REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-SignIn"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Key": "ValidationTechnicalProfile",
                  "Value": {
                    "Values": [
                      {
                        "Key": "TechnicalProfileId",
                        "Value": "REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-SignIn"
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "signInName",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "signInName"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "password",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "password"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "useInputPassword",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "useInputPassword"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Key": "Precondition",
                  "Value": {
                    "$id": "1",
                    "Type": 1,
                    "ExecuteActionsIf": true,
                    "ActionTypes": [
                      1
                    ],
                    "Values": [
                      "needToMigrate",
                      "local"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Key": "TechnicalProfileEnabled",
                  "Value": {
                    "EnabledRule": "Always",
                    "EnabledResult": true,
                    "TechnicalProfile": "login-NonInteractive"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Key": "ValidationTechnicalProfile",
                  "Value": {
                    "Values": [
                      {
                        "Key": "TechnicalProfileId",
                        "Value": "login-NonInteractive"
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "client_id",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "client_id"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "resource",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "resource_id"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "username",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "signInName"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "password",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "password"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "grant_type",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "grant_type"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "scope",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "scope"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "nca",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "nca"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "Exception",
                        "Value": {
                          "Kind": "Handled",
                          "HResult": "80131500",
                          "Message": "The username or password provided in the request are invalid.",
                          "Data": {
                            "IsPolicySpecificError": false
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "Statebag": {
        "SE": {
          "c": "2022-06-03T07:43:42.3832546Z",
          "k": "SE",
          "v": "Self-asserted_local",
          "p": true
        },
        "ComplexItems": "_MachineEventQ, REPRM, TCTX, S_CTP, M_EXCP"
      },
      "Exception": {
        "Kind": "Handled",
        "HResult": "80131500",
        "Message": "The username or password provided in the request are invalid.",
        "Data": {
          "IsPolicySpecificError": false
        }
      },
      "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Action",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.SendRetryHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: "*I could not include all the files in the question text, as it would exceed the max question length*" Please include all relevant debugging information as a [mre] in the body of your question - third party links tend to change and break more often than not and nuke value for future visitors to your question. [ask]

Comment: @esqew Yep, I know that, and I also tried putting everything in the body of the question, but it won't fit. So I don't see how I can live up to that requirement?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is usually caused by configuring incorrect [clientID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy) etc. in the extension file, either for the standard configuration or [extension attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#modify-your-custom-policy).

Using this [utility](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/) will avoid that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I looked through the ClientId and ApplicationObjectId in the AAD-Common technical profile, and I also looked through the client_id and IdTokenAudience (both under MetaData & InputClaims) in the login-NonInteractive technical profile. All of it looks correct. I have now updated my question with the log from Application Insights. Can you spot the problem from that log?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I decided to redo my app registration setup, and strictly follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#register-identity-experience-framework-applications

Previously, I had not used the names `IdentityExperienceFramework` and `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` for the apps, as I thought I could name them according to my use-case, so I had named them `MobileAppApi` (IdentityExperienceFramework) and `MobileApp` (ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework). So now, in addition to the `MobileAppApi` and `MobileApp` app registrations, I also added the `IdentityExperienceFramework` and `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` by following the guide. I updated my `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` to use the app id's for these new apps, and re-tried signing in. I was a bit confused as to why I could not select either of the new `IdentityExperienceFramework` or `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` apps when running the custom SignUpSignIn policy, so then I just picked the `MobileApp` application I has from before.... NOW signing in worked

So, it seems like those `IdentityExperienceFramework` and `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` are some "magic" app registrations you just have to always add.

Comment: Yes they are. Along with the B2C extensions file which has a "do not delete"label.

Comment: The app names are not relevant. The config of those apps is relevant, the behaviour in your answer would indicate they were not configured properly to begin with. Best to use the auto setup tool: https://aka.ms/iefsetup